# Complex with_subelements construct

Tags: ansible

I have the list:

```yaml
    final_list:
      - result:
          name: "val1"
          status: true 
      - result:
          name: "val2"
          status: true
      - skipped:
          path: "path1"
      - result:
          results:
            - result:
                name: "val4"
                status: true
            - result:
                name: "val5"
                status: true
            - skipped:
                path: "path2"
```

I would like check if any status in my list is false.
I started with:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    any_false: true
  when: (item.0.result is defined and item.0.result.status == false) or (item.1.result is defined and item.1.result.status == false) 
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ final_list }}"
    - result.results"
    - skip_missing: True
```

but this task ommit elements from `finally_list` without `results`  in `result`.
I would expect iterate by all elements which contain `status` variable.

I tried also:

```yaml
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ final_list }}"
    - result.results | default([])
```

but get error:

```
msg: msg: the key result should point to a dictionary, got 'None'
```

Comment: What do you mean with `doesn't work correctly` ? You asked it to sweep the floor and it mown the lawn instead  ? Please be specific (expected result, actual result, gap, error message...). Moreover, you seem to be looking for an element that does not exist in your example data. Is that on purpose ? In this case you are probably missing a few `default` filter. Anyway, you have to edit your question to add more details.

Comment: You're right. I edited my topic, moreover I pasted completed list

Comment: Are you 100% sure of your data structure? every `result` at top level has a different structure than when nested inside a `results` list (i.e. `{'result': null, 'name': 'bla', 'status': false}` compared to `{'result':{'name': 'blo', 'status': true}}`. Can you please double check that. It's not really ideal for automated processing and I have the feeling it is a typo.

Comment: Yes, my fault. ```result ```at top level and inside have the same structure. I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to do this a bit differently: get all individual `result` elements in a single flattened list, extract the `status` and check that all elements are true (or not).

The following playbook should be self explanatory (run with `-v` to see intermediate debug)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    final_list:
      - result:
          name: "val1"
          status: true
      - result:
          results:
            - result:
                name: "valA"
                status: false
            - result:
                name: "valB"
                status: true
            - skipped:
                path: "path2"
      - result:
          name: "val2"
          status: true
      - skipped:
          path: "path1"
      - result:
          results:
            - result:
                name: "val4"
                status: true
            - result:
                name: "val5"
                status: true
            - skipped:
                path: "path2"

    # List of all top level elements without nested elements
    single_results: "{{ final_list | rejectattr('result.results', 'defined') }}"

    # Flattened list of all nested result elements.
    # Will work with several nested elements (as you can see from my example data)
    nested_results: "{{ final_list | selectattr('result.results', 'defined') | map(attribute='result.results') | flatten }}"

    # Single list containing top level + nested result elements
    all_results: "{{ single_results + nested_results }}"

    # List of all existing status values in the list of result elements
    all_status: "{{ all_results | selectattr('result.status', 'defined') | map(attribute='result.status') }}"

  tasks:
    - name: Show entire list
      debug:
        var: all_results
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Show list of status
      debug:
        var: all_status
        verbosity: 1

    - name: Make sure all exsiting status are true
      assert:
        that:
          - all_status is all
        fail_msg: "At least one status is false"
        success_msg: "All status are true"
```

which gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Show entire list] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Show list of status] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Make sure all exsiting status are true] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "assertion": "all_status is all",
    "changed": false,
    "evaluated_to": false,
    "msg": "At least one status is false"
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=2    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And if you modify the data to all true (only pasting the last task...)

```
TASK [Make sure all exsiting status are true] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "All status are true"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Q: **"*Check if any status is false.*"**

A: Simple brute force

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        status: "{{ status|d([]) + [item.split(':')|last|trim|bool] }}"
      loop: "{{ (final_list|to_nice_yaml).splitlines() }}"
      when: item is match('^.*\\s+status:\\s+.*$')
```

gives the list of the statuses

```yaml
  status:
  - true
  - true
  - true
  - true
```

See [Testing if a list value is True](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: No status is False.
      when: status is all
```